# json help. correct my json

Tags: json, jsonp, syntax-error

I want to know where my json is incorrect... I know that there is a syntax error so please correct it for me.

```
({
ageRestriction: false,
allowedCountries: [

],
user: {
    ip: '184.173.107.5',
    name: ''
},
player: {
    bufferTime: 60,
    debug: false,
    window: false,
    panel: false,
    autoplay: true,
    smoothing: true,
    scale: 'letterbox'/*none,
    stretch,
    letterbox,
    zoom*/,
    iframeControl: false
},
similar: {
    path: '/actions/control/similaritems/50e54d84d681c00e603935e3',
    preview: '//s.dogannet.tv/q/i/76/600x336/50e54e8cd681c00e603935e4'
},
watermark: {
    path: '//s.dogannet.tv/n/s/content/images/watermark.png?v=2',
    position: 'bottomright'
},
media: {
    id: '50e54d84d681c00e603935e3',
    controller: 'osmf',
    defaultServiceUrl: 'http: //media.netd.com.tr',
    serviceUrl: 'http: //37.48.66.141',
    path: 'S1/HLS_VOD/5ea1_1536/index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94&app=com.dcom&max=1500',
    preview: '//s.dogannet.tv/q/i/76/1600x900/50e54e8cd681c00e603935e4'
},
playlog: {
    callback: function(data){
        data.Application='com.dcom';data.UserName='';data.SessionId='m443qmsgz3mdlnwing2h4qno';data.AnonymId='d241c910-6ae1-4f73-afc4-7cb5991517d4';data.ItemId='50e54d84d681c00e603935e3';data.Url='http: //www.netd.com/diziler/yerli/kanit/kanit-1-sezon/kanit-1-bolum';data.extraData={
            'Agent': navigator.userAgent
        };$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://stats.dogannet.tv/playlog.ashx",
            data: data,
            global: false,
            async: true,
            cache: false
        });
    }
},
heartbeat: {
    interval: 10000,
    callback: function(data){
        data.Application='com.dcom';data.UserName='';data.SessionId='m443qmsgz3mdlnwing2h4qno';data.AnonymId='d241c910-6ae1-4f73-afc4-7cb5991517d4';data.ItemId='50e54d84d681c00e603935e3';data.Url='http: //www.netd.com/diziler/yerli/kanit/kanit-1-sezon/kanit-1-bolum';data.SessionId='m443qmsgz3mdlnwing2h4qno';data.extraData={
            'Agent': navigator.userAgent
        };$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://stats.dogannet.tv/heartbeat.ashx",
            data: data,
            global: false,
            async: false,
            cache: false
        });
    }
},
gemius: {
    materialIdentifier: '1',
    identifier: 'AfVAtKMRq0Ff4WlROmmKr7Po31j_P7s.VdXOiWt3SGL.x7',
    hitCollector: 'http: //str.hit.gemius.pl'
},
comscore: {
    c1: '1',
    c2: '17476642'
},
advert: {
    display: true,
    skipShowDuration: 9,
    preroll: 'http: //app.medyanetads.com/vast.a2?target=netd_videoad_arsivdizi_preroll&channel=50e54d84d681c00e603935e3&category=11534404&keywords=kanit,
    prof_dr_sevil_atasoy,
    engin_benli,
    inci_demirkaya,
    deniz_celiloglu&videoid=463_50e54d84d681c00e603935e3',
    midroll: 'http: //app.medyanetads.com/vast.a2?target=netd_videoad_arsivdizi_midroll&channel=50e54d84d681c00e603935e3',
    postroll: 'http: //app.medyanetads.com/vast.a2?target=netd_videoad_arsivdizi_postroll&channel=50e54d84d681c00e603935e3',
    overlay: 'http: //app.medyanetads.com/vast.a2?target=netd_videoad_arsivdizi_overlay&channel=50e54d84d681c00e603935e3',
    pauseroll: 'http: //app.medyanetads.com/vast.a2?target=netd_videoad_pauseroll&channel=50e54d84d681c00e603935e3',
    viscaleShowDuration: 30,
    viscaleRatio: 0.3889,
    viscale: "http://app.medyanetads.com/vast.a2?target=netd_videoad_viscale&channel=52fddcab68f7320be461c2e9"
},
survey: {
    display: true,
    path: 'http: //app.medyanetads.com/survey/survey.swf',
    domain: 'netd.com'
}
});
});
```

**PLEASE CORRECT** I dont know where is mistake. I wanted to correct it with http://jsonlint.com/   But I can't done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your keys inside double quotes like this:

```json
{
    "ageRestriction": false,
    "allowedCountries": [

    ],
    "user": {
        "ip": "184.173.107.5" 

...
```

If your values are also strings, then they should also be inside double quotes, like in the example above.
See here the exact specification: http://www.json.org/